# Python - Matplotlib name of save fig with function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have done some interpolations and i want to save my fields obtained.
The save name have to contain the variable "field" of the function but i dont know how to add it...

```
def Plot_field(field):
    vmin = field.mean()-5*field.std()
    vmax = field.mean()+5*field.std()
    v = np.linspace(vmin, vmax, 15, endpoint=True)
    plt.tricontourf(Xnew, Ynew, field, v, cmap=plt.cm.hot)
    x = plt.colorbar(ticks=v)
    print x
    # plt.scatter(Pos_integr_inst_tplus1[:,1], Pos_integr_inst_tplus1[:,2],marker='s',s=20.)    
    plt.savefig("field" + str(instant[0]) + ".png")
    # plt.show()
```

For example, i have my 2D array V and i would like by using :

```
Plot_field(V)
```

to get a save whose name is "V02.png" with 02 corresping to a specific instant

Comment: What is `field`? Looks like an array (`.mean()`), how do you want to put an array into the name of a file?

Comment: It is an array but i would like to automate the field name in the save fig!

Comment: What do you mean by "the field name"?

Comment: To use Plot_field, i have to specify my 2D array field and i have a several number to generate, so i would like to find in my plot saves the name of the field

Comment: Sorry if i m not enough clear

Comment: You can not access name of variable within function, as it is evaluated before passed to function. You can search locals() or globals () for variable name with same value, but it is not very elegant. Best will be pass the name directly to function as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it seems impossible, i have to add, "name" in the function and that works

```
def Plot_field(field,name):
    vmin = field.mean()-5*field.std()
    vmax = field.mean()+5*field.std()
    v = np.linspace(vmin, vmax, 15, endpoint=True)
    plt.tricontourf(Xnew, Ynew, field, v, cmap=plt.cm.hot)
    x = plt.colorbar(ticks=v)
    print x
    # plt.scatter(Pos_integr_inst_tplus1[:,1], Pos_integr_inst_tplus1[:,2],marker='s',s=20.)    
    plt.savefig(name+ str(instant[0]) + ".png")
    # plt.show()

# Plot_field(V)

Plot_field(VM,"VM")
```

Comment: Your plot function should also take in an `Axes` object as the first argument instead of relying on global state to hit the 'right' axes.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
plt.savefig("field" + str(field) + str(instant[0]) + ".png")
```